# Inherit outer controller's scope from within ng-include without a service?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope

In AngularJS is it possible to inherit the parent controller's scope from within an included partial instead of passing the data through an injected service?

Example case:

Let's say `ParentCtrl`'s scope looks like: `{ testData: 'testing stuff' }`

```
<div ng-controller="ParentCtrl">
    Here we're defined: {{testData}}
    <div ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>
</div>
```

And inside `partial.html`:

```
<em>Inherited: {{testData}}</em>
```

So the partial doesn't even need it's own controller for this. If this is impossible though and you can only pass injected data between controllers via a service why has Angular done things this way?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, that's actually how it works by default.  `ng-include` always creates a new scope and:

> A "child scope" (prototypically) inherits properties from its parent
>   scope.

[See the docs on Scope.](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope)

[Here](http://plnkr.co/edit/JJMBQ2cekbdrqGWigtpM?p=preview) is an example plunker.

**Edit:** Also, I just noticed a syntax issue in your original question.  The template should be surrounded in single quotes.  Change `<div ng-include="partial.html"></div>` to  `<div ng-include="'partial.html'"></div>`

Answer (score 0):

Playing around with the example Plunkr in the [ngInclude documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngInclude#example), I'm able to access the parent controller's scope from within the partial. For example, change the contents of `template1.html` to:

```
Content of template1.html {{ template }}
```

Per the docs, `ngInclude` creates a new scope, which means you'll need to observe the angular best practice of "having a dot in your scope" (accessing objects on the scope instead of primitive values), to avoid problems with broken references. You can check out [this Stack Overflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14049480/535666) for more information.